# Should I continue adding a question if I have found the answer myself?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I start typing a question (which may be interesting and useful), but then think and/or google more and find answer myself.

Should I just close the window or add the question with my answer to enrich solutions database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can/should continue adding that question, but only if you didn't find the answer on StackOverflow.  :-)

Comment: +1 The sites are about providing answers to people, no matter when in time they're needed!  Benefit future searchers with your new found knowledge.

Comment: Actually I use SuperUser more. OK, adding the question and the answer: http://superuser.com/questions/141290/.