# Shall I remove my question if I found the answer myself?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)
>   [Should I continue adding a question if I have found the answer myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49922/should-i-continue-adding-a-question-if-i-have-found-the-answer-myself)

Shall I remove my question if nobody answered it and I found the answer myself, or should I keep it?

Here is the question I am writing about:

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529096/what-does-it-mean-if-the-icon-beside-my-mq4-expert-advisor-is-gray)

Comment: No, don't remove it, answer it, as you did. You are allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions. And you can even accept the answer.

Comment: No.Post the answer and accept it. See [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, don't remove. Help other people - that is the main purpose. You even can earn [**Self-learner**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) badge (Answered your own question with score of 3 or more.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if the question is good and potentially interesting to others, leave it up. You're entirely wel­come to answer your own question, and if others find this informative they will probably even reward you with upvotes.

On the other hand, if the question is extremely specific, or based on a very well known issue or a "silly mis­take" (like a typo or confusing variable names) which is unlikely to offer any insight to others, then you might like to remove the question.

Basically, ask yourself if you would have found your time well spent if you had been randomly browsing SO and hit upon your question, and take that as an indicator.